# 30 seconds timeout solutions not working

Tags: php, html, browser, timeout

I have tried every possible solution for my php file 30 seconds timeout, but nothing works.
Is it possible that my new configurations that I put in my code don't take affect and still works according to the configurations which are in Goddady's default php.ini?

Comment: can you post every possible solution you've tried so far?

Comment: increased the 'max_execution_time' to more than 30 seconds

Comment: This is a question you should ask the service provider.

Comment: can you post the php.ini file you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick google shows that you can't change that setting on GoDaddy shared servers. Can't be done: http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/set-max_execution_time-and-max_input_time/

That was 2 years ago, and so probably not changed. Go virtual or get a new host?

Answer (score 1):

Yet it is possible that a hosting provider does not allow overrides for some settings or for all settings.

That's what the httpd.conf configuration directive `AllowOverride None`/`AllowOverride All` does.

Use `ini_get('max_execution_time')` to check what the execution time becomes after you've tried a solutin. If it doesn't change it's obvious that solution didn't work.

Comment: When I set the 'max_execution_time' to value less than 30 (1 second for example) I get this Error: "Maximum execution time of 1 second exceeded". But When I set it to a larger number like 60 I get "500 (Internal Server) Error"

Comment: Probably Go-Daddy are killing the task when you exceed the 30 second maximum they allow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you've put it in the correct location to be identified? if so, you can look into this link
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5647/why-isnt-my-phpini-file-taking-effect

you've provided too little information about your server. if it is linux, here what they said:

> On Linux Shared Hosting accounts, you can kill the Web processes to
>   get your php.ini (PHP 4) or php5.ini (PHP 5) file to take effect.

Comment: if you check the link, there are information about windows too

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work on a Godaddy shared Linux account by creating a .user.ini file in the hosting root.

My changes are visible with phpinfo()

Answer (score 0):

remember that when setting your own custom php.ini file with Godaddy you may pull up timezone warning messages. In which case you have to also define the default timezone in the php.ini file, for example:

```
date.timezone="Europe/London"
```

More about this problem here:

https://uk.godaddy.com/help/why-did-i-receive-a-timezone-error-with-my-php-website-6703